# Security Issues About URL Basic Authentication

Tags: php, html

Some web pages could be protected by a basic HTTP authentication (username, password), and these could be specified this way;

```
https://user:password@www.example.com
```

Now, when you view the source of a web page visiting this url (in google);

```
view-source:https://www.example.com
```

You can see the links with the basic authentication provided, like this;

```
<a href="https://user:password@example.com> click here </a>
```

What can we do to avoid this security issues? Since I'm using PHP I've tried to insert the user/password in variables but it gets shown the same way.

Comment: `What can we do to avoid this security issues?` Don't use this kind of authentication. It isn't designed to be used this way.

Answer (score 2):

username:password in the URL is [NOT RECOMMENDED](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters) and has been [DEPRECATED](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

and no longer allowed in many browsers

So the answer to *What can we do to avoid this security issues?*  is to not use it

Comment: thanks & what do use instead?

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer

Comment: @JohnConde I added the obvious answer, which is what you said too

Comment: @ItDev why can't you just remove the username/password and let the browser handle auth?